# How to automatically add a new record to the second table if a record was added in the first table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

There is a first table M_TAX_ORG and when inserting new record, the second table M_TAX_ORG_ADM_INFO should also add record. (As you can see from the screenshots, M_TAX_ORG_ADM_INFO is associated with M_TAX_ORG ) Are there ready-made scripts? Maybe with trigger?

Link to db: [db_trigger](https://dbfiddle.uk/xCTJJKWi)

[image]

[image]

I tried this script. But it's not correct.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER M_TAX_ORG_AFTER_INSERT
    AFTER INSERT
       ON M_TAX_ORG
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    v_M_TAX_ORG_ADM_INFO_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT max(M_TAX_ORG_ADM_INFO_ID) + 1 INTO v_M_TAX_ORG_ADM_INFO_id FROM M_TAX_ORG_ADM_INFO;
    INSERT INTO M_TAX_ORG_ADM_INFO
        ( M_TAX_ORG_ADM_INFO_ID,
          RNN,
          IIN_BIN,
          NAME_R,
          NAME_K,
          M_TAX_ORG_ID,
          IS_MAIN,
          IS_ACTIVE,
          EXTERNAL_ID )
    VALUES
        ( v_M_TAX_ORG_ADM_INFO_id,
          :new.RNN,
          :new.IIN_BIN,
          :new.NAME_R,
          :new.NAME_K,
          :new.M_TAX_ORG_ID,
          :new.IS_MAIN,
          :new.IS_ACTIVE,
          :new.EXTERNAL_ID
        );
end;
```

Comment: A trigger seems to be the correct way for this, so why does your trigger not work? I think it would be good when you create a fiddle with your DB schema, so people can replicate your issue. You can open this link, add your data and then share the new link: https://dbfiddle.uk/7Jxju0AY

Comment: [db_trigger](https://dbfiddle.uk/xCTJJKWi) <-- link is here

Comment: The trigger does work. In your fiddle you only forgot to create several columns in the tables. Here is the corrected fiddle, showing that the trigger works: https://dbfiddle.uk/6wx-KvTy. The only problem I see is that there are two column names NAME_R and NANE_R, which may be a typo.

Comment: But in db, I have this errors --> PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.NANE_R'; 
PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.IS_MAIN'; 
PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.EXTERNAL_ID'

Comment: The error message seems quite clear. In the fiddle you have NANE_R. Does your table m_tax_org have a column named NANE_R? Or only a column named NAME_R? Does your table m_tax_org have a column named IS_MAIN? Does your table m_tax_org have a column named EXTERNAL_ID?

Comment: I've corrected. Can u check it: [db_trigger](https://dbfiddle.uk/UL9cSHF6)

Comment: It turns out there is no IS_MAIN column and EXTERNAL_ID

Comment: If they don't exist, you cannot refer to them as :new.IS_MAIN  and :new.EXTERNAL_ID of course. Remove the two columns from the insert statement and you are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This trigger is correct

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER M_TAX_ORG_AFTER_INSERT
    AFTER INSERT
       ON M_TAX_ORG
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO M_TAX_ORG_ADM_INFO
        ( M_TAX_ORG_ADM_INFO_ID,
          RNN,
          IIN_BIN,
          NAME_R,
          NAME_K,
          M_TAX_ORG_ID,
          IS_MAIN,
          IS_ACTIVE,
          EXTERNAL_ID )
    VALUES
        ( SEQ_M_TAX_ORG_ADM_INFO.nextval,
          :new.RNN,
          :new.IIN_BIN,
          :new.NAME_R,
          :new.NAME_K,
          :new.M_TAX_ORG_ID,
          1,
          :new.IS_ACTIVE,
          (round(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() * 999999999999) + 1)
        );
END;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).